# apache doesn't cache jpeg images

Tags: apache, caching, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, browser-cache

Im using ec2 and s3 with my website https://he.mypen.net. Changed my apache configurations to:

```
#Set caching on image files for 11 months
<filesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js|woff|eot|TrueType|svg)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 11 month"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=17280000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

The cache works well for woff,css, js,png files, but doesnt work for my s3 jpegs
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request for images on S3 is not passing through Apache. With this, any configuration you do to Apache to set cache headers wont do anything.

Instead, you can set metadata which also includes cache headers directly on objects within S3.

For more information on that, take a look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html